Failed to build GCC with uClibc-ng-1.0.48
I am trying to build a cross compiler of GCC for mips32 with uClibc.
I downloaded GCC-10.3.0 and uClibc-ng-1.0.48, the system environment is setup as follows,
export ARCH=mips
export TARGET=mips-linux-uclibc
export PREFIX=/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output
export TARGET_PREFIX=$PREFIX/$TARGET
export PATH=$PREFIX/bin:$PATH

I want to have the build files installed to /home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output.
For the first build of gcc, the configuration is as follows,
configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--with-sysroot=$PREFIX \
--with-local-prefix=$PREFIX --with-native-system-header-dir=/$TARGET/include \
--enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-linker-build-id --disable-multilib \
--disable-werror --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-shared \
--disable-nls --target=$TARGET --disable-libmudflap \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-arch-64=mips64r2 \
--with-float=hard --with-mips-plt --disable-threads

It is built and installed well.
After successfully configured and built uClibc-ng-1.0.48 and libgcc, I tried to build the full-functional GCC, as follows,
configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--with-sysroot=/ \
--with-local-prefix=$PREFIX \
--with-native-system-header-dir=/$TARGET_PREFIX/include \
--enable-languages=c,c++ \
--enable-linker-build-id \
--disable-multilib \
--disable-werror --disable-nls --target=$TARGET --disable-libmudflap \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-arch-64=mips64r2 \
--with-float=hard --with-mips-plt --disable-threads

This time, I hit an error as follows,
g++ -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilto -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/lto -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include -I/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/./gmp -I/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/gmp -I/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/./mpfr/src -I/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mpfr/src -I/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mpc/src  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace   -o lto/lto-dump.o -MT lto/lto-dump.o -MMD -MP -MF lto/.deps/lto-dump.TPo ../../gcc/lto/lto-dump.c
g++ -no-pie   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  gcov.o json.o \
        hash-table.o ggc-none.o libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a  -L./../zlib -lz -o gcov
/usr/bin/ld: libcommon.a(diagnostic.o): in function `diagnostic_action_after_output(diagnostic_context*, diagnostic_t)':
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/gcc/../../gcc/diagnostic.c:581: undefined reference to `backtrace_full'
/usr/bin/ld: ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a(state.o): in function `backtrace_create_state':
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/libbacktrace/../../libbacktrace/state.c:66: undefined reference to `backtrace_alloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:3014: gcov] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4406: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc'
make: *** [Makefile:966: all] Error 2

And I checked the build directory of libbacktrace, I got.
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t   5328 May 25 19:52 libbacktrace/atomic.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  12432 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/backtrace.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 277568 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/dwarf.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 181392 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/elf.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  16920 May 25 19:52 libbacktrace/fileline.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  23304 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/mmap.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  13320 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/mmapio.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  11336 May 25 19:52 libbacktrace/posix.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  14472 May 25 19:52 libbacktrace/print.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  10472 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/simple.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t  11840 May 25 19:53 libbacktrace/sort.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t t   9808 May 25 20:10 libbacktrace/state.o

The backtrace_alloc is defined in libbacktrace/alloc.c, which is NOT built.
The backtrace_full is defined in libbacktrace/backtrace.c, which is built.
Updated with more progress.
I found the reference to the 'undefined' functions and commented them out, then make gcc, I got following errors.
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: /home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/lib/libc.a(__uClibc_main.os): in function `__uClibc_fini':
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: __uClibc_main.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `__fini_array_end'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: /home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/lib/libc.a(__uClibc_main.os): in function `__uClibc_main':
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_start'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: __uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_end'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: __uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: __uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: ./libgcc_s.so.1.tmp: hidden symbol `__fini_array_end' isn't defined
/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/output/mips-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:994: libgcc_s.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc/mips-linux-uclibc/libgcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13287: all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/t/develop/mips_gnu_uclibc/src/gcc/mips-linux-uclibc'
make: *** [Makefile:964: all] Error 2

So I don't know what is wrong with my configuration and build, and how can I build the full-function gcc for mips ?
